# What module(s) do I need to include to get 5.seconds to work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, datetime, libraries

Because apparently `require 'date'` doesn't include the method hours or seconds etc:

```
undefined method `hours' for 5:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
```

Am I missing something? Is 5.seconds only something you can do in Rails? If so, what is the require statement I need to get this to work in a ruby script?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following works for me

```
irb
>> require 'active_support'
=> true
>> 5.hours
=> 18000 seconds
```

Depending on your environment and rails version you may need to `require 'rubygems'` this should be done before the `require 'active_support'` line.

You may also have to `require 'activesupport'` instead of active_support if you have an older version of rails.

Comment: I'll accept this answer if you edit your post (I will downvote if you dont edit it.) You need to require 'rubygems' first before active_support.

Comment: The original script works for me as is but edited anyway. Please note that for library code requiring rubygems is generally considered bad practice see http://www.rubyinside.com/why-using-require-rubygems-is-wrong-1478.html

Comment: well its not bad practice when its THE THING you need for it to actually work.

Comment: This isn't working for me on OS X with Rails 3.2.1 installed, either with a require 'rubygems' statement or without. Anything special I need to do?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out, I needed to add "require 'active_support/core_ext/numeric/time'", based on a comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5905875/53597

Answer (score 101):

Old question, but for the googlers like me:

```
require 'active_support/time'
```

For gem version 3.2.11, anyway.

Comment: True, just doing require "active_support" won't be sufficient as mentioned in the accepted answer.

Comment: This works for me in irb. But after adding `gem 'active_support/time'` to the gemfile, I get: `Could not find gem 'active_support/time' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.`

Comment: Should be marked as the right answer. require 'active_support' is not enough (at least on ruby version > '2.4.2')

Comment: If you're running a `ruby` project without `rails` ensure to install `rails` into the project using the command `gem install rails` since this extension is a `rails` extension. And then add the `require 'active_support/time'` in your project.

Answer (score 3):

ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Numeric::Time maybe

Comment: Link: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Numeric/Time.html