# How do I add two weeks to Time.now?

Tags: ruby, time

How can I add two weeks to the current Time.now in Ruby? I have a small Sinatra project that uses DataMapper and before saving, I have a field populated with the current time PLUS two weeks, but is not working as needed. Any help is greatly appreciated! I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError at /
undefined method `weeks' for 2:Fixnum
```

Here is the code for the Model:

```
class Job
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,           Serial
  property :position,     String
  property :location,     String
  property :email,        String
  property :phone,        String
  property :description,  Text
  property :expires_on,   Date
  property :status,       Boolean
  property :created_on,   DateTime
  property :updated_at,   DateTime

  before :save do
    t = Time.now
    self.expires_on = t + 2.week
    self.status = '0'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You don't have such nice helpers in plain Ruby. You can add seconds:

```
Time.now + (2*7*24*60*60)
```

But, fortunately, there are many date helper libraries out there (or build your own ;) )

Comment: If the only thing you need out of ActiveSupport is this code, I think this is the best solution (which you could wrap in your own custom method). Seems silly to load the entire ActiveSupport code just for this one calculation...

Comment: Multiplying numbers to add dates is generally a bad idea. Raw multiplication doesn't take into account things like leap years and how different months have different numbers of days and so on. The reason there are Date/Time classes in any language is to encapsulate the proper date math so you're not doing manual math like this.

Comment: @SamuelGoodwin I don't believe you. Can you please give an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: @J-_-L At noon on the day before the fall time change for Daylight Savings, noon the next day is 25 hours away.  On noon the day before the spring change for Daylight Savings, noon the next day is 23 hours away.

Comment: You can `require 'active_support/core_ext'` and get the day/days week/weeks, and others without loading *all* of activesupport.

Comment: @messick If you want one day, then you should use 1.days, not  24.hours. But if you really want 24 hours, then the different hours are correct. 
e=Time.now; print e.to_s +  "\n"; print (e + 96.hours).to_s + "\n"; print (e + 4.days).to_s + "\n"
2014-10-29 11:08:38 -0700
2014-11-02 10:08:38 -0800
2014-11-02 11:08:38 -0800

Answer (score 58):

Ruby `Date` class has [methods](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/Date.html#M000385) to add days and months in addition to seconds in Time.
An example:

```
require 'date'
t = DateTime.now
puts t      # => 2011-05-06T11:42:26+03:00

# Add 14 days
puts t + 14 # => 2011-05-20T11:42:26+03:00

# Add 2 months
puts t >> 2 # => 2011-07-06T11:42:26+03:00

# And if needed, make Time object out of it
(t + 14).to_time   # => 2011-05-20 11:42:26 +0300
```

Comment: I have Ruby 1.8.7 which I had Ruby 2.0!

Comment: +1 for using the standard library and not using Active Support. It's also worth noting that the methods for manipulating the times are found in the [Date class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html)

Answer (score 23):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support/core_ext/numeric/time'
self.expires = 2.weeks.from_now
```

Comment: That is not working for me. I'm still getting the same error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is the active_support gem installed? Do a `gem install rails` and get yourself a nice fresh copy of it.  It's very handy outside of Rails.

Comment: It might help to read section 1.1 of http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html. Active_Support doesn't load anything using `require 'active_support'` any more.

Comment: the Tin Man is correct. You would need to `require 'active_support/core_ext/numeric/time'`

Comment: In version `4.1.6` of gem `activesupport` `require 'active_support/core_ext/numeric/time'` doesn't include function `advance` for `Date` needed for `2.weeks.from_now`. I solved it with `require 'active_support/all'` and it works. Why bother when you can add all gem functions at once?

Comment: `require 'active_support/core_ext/numeric/time'` will get you `Date.today + 3.days`

Answer (score 20):

You have to use seconds to do calculation between dates, but you can use the Time class as a helper to get the seconds from the date part elements.

```
Time.now + 2.week.to_i
```

EDIT: As mentioned by @iain you will need Active Support to accomplish usign `2.week.to_i`, if you can't (or don't want to) have this dependency you can always use the `+` operator to add seconds to a `Time` instance ([*time + numeric → time* docs here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html#method-i-2B))

```
Time.now + (60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 2)
```

Comment: This needs an extra library loaded in, I'm guessing Active Support. -1 from me.

Comment: @iain good point! just added some docs reference and a non-active support fallback answer

Comment: a -1 has now turned into a +1! :) Thanks for updating the answer.

Comment: `Time.now + 2.week` works just fine without the .to_i (at least in Rails)

Comment: @aaron-coding I see... well, I guess it depends on the ruby/ActiveSupport version

Answer (score 19):

I think `week/weeks` is defined in the [active support numeric](http://rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/3.0.7/Numeric) extension

```
$ ruby -e 'p Time.now'
2011-05-05 22:27:04 -0400
$ ruby -r active_support/core_ext/numeric -e 'p Time.now + 2.weeks'
2011-05-19 22:27:07 -0400
```

Answer (score 8):

#### You can use these 3 patterns

```
# you have NoMethod Error undefined method 
require 'active_support/all'

# Tue, 28 Nov 2017 11:46:37 +0900
Time.now + 2.weeks

# Tue, 28 Nov 2017 11:46:37 +0900
Time.now + 2.week

# Tue Nov 28 11:48:24 +0900 2017
2.weeks.from_now
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<%current_time=Time.now
  current_time_s=current_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').to_s #show currrent date time
 current_time= Time.now + (60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 250)
 current_time_e=current_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').to_s #show datetime after week
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like mine too :)

```
def minor?(dob)
  n = DateTime.now
  a = DateTime.parse(dob)
  a >> 12*18 > n
end
```

Saves you the trouble of thinking about leap years and seconds. Just works out of the box.